# File not readable in Laravel

Tags: php, io, laravel-3

Im trying to open a template with PHPExcel, in laravel.

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(URL::to_asset('myfile.xls'));
```

However, I get a File is not readable error.

When I do this...

```
if(is_readable(URL::to_asset('myfile.xls')){
    echo "is readable";
 } else { echo "nope";}
```

I get "nope" returned to me.

If i echo an image from this same asset directory, it displays fine.

```
<img src='URL::to_asset('img/test.png')'>
```

However if i do this....it also return "nope"

```
if(is_readable(URL::to_asset(img/test.png')){
    echo "is readable";
 } else { echo "nope";}
```

What is going on here?

Why if I visit the link in my browser the files display fine.

yet when I test them for readbility, they return false results??

This is Larave 3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function `is_readable()` expects a system file as argument, so does `PHPExcel_IOFactory::load()`; you are passing a URL instead, which will always fail.

You need the local system path to the file and use that instead.